# Which VISOR does LeVar Burton own?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

[image]

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64175/1224) says that Penny Juday, Senior Art Dept Coordinator for TNG, owns the original from the beginning of the series and that another was sold at auction to an unknown buyer.

However, in [2012 LeVar Burton was offering a chance to wear his VISOR](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/26/business/media/star-trek-prop-to-help-reading-rainbow-grow.html) as a Kickstarter reward.

> LeVar Burton is leveraging a chance to wear **the original Visor** he sported as the character Geordi La Forge in “Star Trek: The Next Generation” in exchange for a donation to the actor’s more recent venture[...]

Which VISOR does he own?

Comment: "*LeVar Burton is levaraging*" ... yes, he does look a bit older now.

Comment: He needs to update/brighten up his man cave.

Answer (score 21):

The prize came with this picture;

[image]

As you can see, the banding around the outside (and the grill inside) are both plain silver rather than the typical silver and gold [you see on the show](https://www.startrek.com/sites/default/files/styles/1200x628/public/images/2019-07/aa169b49b583a2b5af89203c2b78c67c.jpg?itok=68Dy5_sD). The only time Geordi wore a VISOR that was plain silver was in the flashback sequence in [*TNG: Identity Crisis*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Identity_Crisis_(episode)), set some 6 years before [*TNG: Encounter at Farpoint*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode)). The script describes it thusly;

> GEORDI moves into view, holding a Tricorder. (Note: Geordi is younger here, wearing **a slightly different, earlier version of his VISOR.**)
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Identity Crisis - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/192.txt)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

It would seem that this is the VISOR that Levar Burton owns.

Answer (score 9):

From [the man himself](https://twitter.com/levarburton/status/914522198248898561):

> *"I am in possession of the one I wore everyday on set for several
> years. Anyone who claims otherwise, is not in possession of all the
> facts!"*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/levarburton/status/914522198248898561)</sup></sub>

Comment: This seems to be in response to my pointing him at this question :-)